# I don't understand the proof of Corollary 4.8.7 in the book of Ethier and Kurtz

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

I'm trying to understand the proof of [Corollary 8.7 of Chapter 4 in the book *Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence* by Stewart N. Ethier, Thomas G. Kurtz](https://books.google.com/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=%22Suppose+in+Theorem+8.2+that+the%22+ethier&source=bl&ots=7ayJy0Q0wB&sig=ACfU3U1-NcesD4fDtpK-fSkReImDePfa5g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9j8enweHhAhWIY1AKHT66ALsQ6AEwA3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Suppose%20in%20Theorem%208.2%20that%20the%22%20ethier&f=false). Here is the theorem and its proof:

[image: Corollary 8.7]

And here are the relevant parts they refer to:

[image: Corollary 8.6]

[image: Theorem 8.2]

> There are two things that I don't understand:
>
> 1. Why do they use $\chi_{\left\{\:\tau_n\:>\:\color{red}{1}\:\right\}}$ (indicator function of $\left\{\tau_n>1\right\}$) in the definition of $\varphi_n$. Wouldn't it make more sense to use $\chi_{\left\{\:\tau_n\:>\:\color{red}{T}\:\right\}}$ instead?
> 2. By definition, $f_n(Y_n(t))-\int_0^tg_n(Y_n(s))\:{\rm d}s$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal F^{Y_n}$ generated by $Y_n$. But why is $\xi_n(t)-\int_0^t\varphi_n(s)\:{\rm d}s$ still a $\mathcal F^{Y_n}$-martingale? Since they seem to conclude the proof with Theorem 8.2 (c), it seems like they are assuming this (since in Theorem 8.2, $(\xi_n,\varphi_n)\in\hat{\mathcal A}_n$)

Comment: The printing of this book is often a bit hard to read, especially with $t$s in subscripts. Would question $1$ be resolved if you had $\phi_n(t) = g_n(Y_n(t)) \chi_{\tau_n \geq t}$?

Comment: I've looked in my print copy and that's definitely a $t$ and not a $1$.

Comment: @RhysSteele The funny thing is, I've ran text recognition to be sure and it said it's a $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this all stems from you misreading the subscript in the definition of $\varphi_n$ (very understandable, it's almost impossible to discern subscripts in scanned copies of this book). The correct definition of $\varphi_n(t)$ is
$$\varphi_n(t) = g_n(Y_n(t)) \chi_{\{\tau_n > t\}}.$$
The reason you want this is that it gives $\xi_n(t) - \int_0^t \varphi_n(s) ds$ the form of a stopped martingale. You've realised that $M_n(t) := f_n(Y_n(t))-\int_0^tg_n(Y_n(s))\:{\rm d}s$ is a martingale. Now notice that with correct definition of $\varphi_n$, we have
$$\xi_n(t) - \int_0^t \varphi_n(s) ds = M_n(t)^{\tau_n} := M_n(t \wedge \tau_n)$$
so $\xi_n(t) - \int_0^t \varphi_n(s) ds$ is at least a local martingale for your filtration. Now you should be able to just use the usual tricks to see that this local martingale is a true martingale.

Comment: I know there is no immediate relation, but I'm actually trying to use the result of the theorem in the context of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035383/47771. Could you take a look? The question really struggles me since a while. It's a bit complicated to state and I think I got muddled by all the details. But I guess the solution is almost trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes more sense now. Just one subtlety: Shouldn't we define $$\tau_n:=\inf\left\{t>0:\left(\int_0^t\left|g_n(Y_n(s))\right|^2\:{\rm d}s\right)^{\frac12}>\sqrt t(\left\|g\right\|_\infty+1)\right\}$$ instead of the definition of $\tau_n$ given in the book? I guess this doesn't matter in the end, but $\tau_d$ should be defined with $$\sup_{y\in G_n}|g_n(y)|\le\sup_{y\in G_n}|g_n(y)-(\pi_ng)(y)|+\sup_{y\in G_n}|(\pi_ng)(y)|\le1+\left\|g\right\|_\infty$$ for $n$ large enough in mind.

Comment: And regarding the true martingale property: Would your attempt be to show boundedness? We should have $$|M_n(\tau_n\wedge t)|\le\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|f_n\right\|_\infty+\sqrt t\left(\int_0^{\tau_n\:\wedge\:t}\left|g_n(Y_n(s))\right|^2\:{\rm d}s\right)^{\frac12}\le\underbrace{\sqrt t\sqrt{\tau_n\wedge t}}_{\le\:t}(1+\left\|g\right\|_\infty).$$ Is that sufficient?

Comment: I'd still be interested in an answer.

Comment: I don't have time to go through the proof to look for the answer to the first question but it really shouldn't matter. The two stopping times ought to have roughly the same behaviour and I would trust Ethier and Kurtz to have a good reason for their choice. For your second question, you've shown that on bounded time intervals the local martingale $M_n(t \wedge \tau_n)$ is uniformly bounded. This is a standard criterion for a local martingale to be a true martingale (remove the localising sequence appearing in the martingale property using the DCT).

Comment: Sorry, as I look at the problem now, why isn't it immediate that $\xi_n(t) - \int_0^t \varphi_n(s) ds$ is a (strict) martingale? We have shown that it is equal to the stopped martingale $M_n^{\tau_n}$. And a stopped (strict) martingale is a (strict) martingale; not only a local martingale. What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing an important subtlety, but the optional stopping theorem should hold for all a.s. right-continuous martingales and stopping times wrt a common filtration. So, it should be applicable without further ado. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, apologies. I made a stupid mistake and was thinking of trying to prove that a stopped U.I. martingale is again U.I. We can definitely alway apply optional stopping to the stopping time $t \wedge \tau_n$ since this stopping time is bounded.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One last question: I'm struggling to see why $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\text E\left[\left(\int_0^T\left|\varphi_n(t)\right|^2\:{\rm d}t\right)^{\frac12}\right]<\infty.$$ We can write $$\left(\int_0^T|\varphi_n(t)|^2\:{\rm d}t\right)^{\frac12}=\left(\int_0^{\tau_n\:\wedge\:T}|g_n(Y_n(t))|^2\:{\rm d}t\right)^{\frac12}\le$$

Comment: $$1_{\left\{\tau_n\le T\right\}}\left(\int_0^{\tau_n}|g_n(Y_n(t))|^2\:{\rm d}t\right)^{\frac12}+1_{\left\{\tau_n>T\right\}}\left(\int_0^{τ_n}T(\left\|g\right\|^2+1)$$
(I have no idea why but the second equation doesn't render correctly (that's why I've split the equation into two parts). Hopefully you can read it anyway). The second summand is no problem (since $\text P[τ_n>T]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$, but how can we bound the first summand?

Comment: Ah, sorry, we should have $$\left(\int_0^{\tau_n\:\wedge\:t}|g_n(Y_n(s))|^2\:{\rm d}s\right)^{\frac12}\le(\tau_n\wedge t)(\left\|g\right\|_\infty^2+1)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0,$$ by definition of $\tau_n$ (if I'm not missing anything).

Comment: Yes, that works and solves your issue.

Comment: It's not clear to me how we need to construct the high probability sets in the implication "(g) $\Rightarrow$ (f)". I've asked for that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3231951/47771. Maybe you can take a look.

Comment: While Ethier/Kurtz prove that (g) implies (f), I guess that the other direction fails to hold (otherwise they would surely mention that they are equivalent). Are we at least able to show that if (f) holds, then for all $f\in L$ and $t>s\ge0$, there are $G_n\subseteq E_n$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname P\left[Y_n(s)\in G_n\right]=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{y\in G_n}|T_n(t-s)\pi_nf(y)-\pi_nT(t-s)f(y)|=0$?

Comment: You have a bad habit of leaving comment chains that are far too long under answers. This is certainly not the same question and shouldnt be a comment but could be another question.